# Need XSLT transformation to convert Input XML to Output XML

Tags: xml, xslt

HI,

I am looking to convert input XML to OUTput XML using XSLT.

Input XML is as below

```
<ALLFields id="0001">
  <field name="ComputerName">ABC</field>
  <field name="ComputerType">Windows</field>
  <field name="DatabaseName" />
  <field name="CPULevel">10</field>
</ALLFields>
```

OUTPUT XML what i need is

```
<entry id="0001">
<ComputerName>ABC</ComputerName>
<ComputerType>Windows</ComputerType>
<DatabaseName />
<CPULevel>10</CPULevel>
</entry>
```

Comment: Could you format your question so that the XML schema can be read and provide what you have already tried

Answer (score 3):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="ALLFields">
     <entry id="{@id}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
     </entry>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="field">
  <xsl:element name="{@name}">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document (corrected to be well-formed):**

```
<ALLFields id="0001">
    <field name="ComputerName">ABC</field>
    <field name="ComputerType">Windows</field>
    <field name="DatabaseName" />
    <field name="CPULevel">10</field>
</ALLFields>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<entry id="0001">
   <ComputerName>ABC</ComputerName>
   <ComputerType>Windows</ComputerType>
   <DatabaseName/>
   <CPULevel>10</CPULevel>
</entry>
```

Comment: Using this code:

`var myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform(); 
myXslTrans.Load("Files/NaughtyXSLT_Transform.xsl");
myXslTrans.Transform("Files/NaughtyXSLT_InputXML.xml","NaughtyXSLT_OutputXML.xml");`

Does not work, jeez I cannot edit this comment for some reason!

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="AllFields">
    <entry id="{@id}">
        <xsl:for-each select="field">
            <xsl:element name="{@name}">
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </entry>
</xsl:template>
```

Not tested though.

Comment: There is no element named `entry` in the provided source XML document.

Comment: It was `<AllFields> ... </entry>` so I chose `entry`. Thanks, updated.